# Need to send a Broadcast in onActivityResult but target fragment is still paused

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, onactivityresult

I have fragments F1 and F2.

F1 contains a BroadcastReceiver which is registered/unregistered in F1's onResume/onPause.

When I start an activity for result from F2, both F1 and F2 are paused. I eventually get F2's onActivityResult called. From there, I need to send a broadcast to F1, but at this moment onResume was not called yet, so the BroadcastReceives is not listening.

What's the best solution in this scenario?

For now, I'm registering the receiver in F1's onAttach/onDetach, so that it's active when onActivityResult executes. It doesn't look like the best solution though.

Comment: why not checking the data that needs to be update in F1 on it's onResume or visibility? what is it exactly you send on the broadcast?

Comment: Don't use broadcasts and Receivers to try to pass data between Fragments in the same Activity. Use the standard method of passing data via the hosting Activity.

Comment: @Shahar In the broadcast I ask F1 to take an action(select an item in the nav drawer). Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah, I'll stop using a BroadcastReceiver in this case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts, I concluded that the best way to go would be to stop using a BroadcastReceiver, and instead, use the onActivityResult from the Activity containing F1 and F2. In this method, I call directly a F1's method which takes the action expected.

Thanks Mike. M for the suggestion.